# Exclude dependency and import other version

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management, spring-retry

I want to be able to import `org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.2-SNAPSHOT` using Gradle.

However, spring-retry dependency (of different version): `org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.5.RELEASE`  is coming from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration -> 2.3.3.RELEASE`.

How can I exclude the dependency coming from spring-boot-starter-integration and rather import 1.3.2-SNAPSHOT version?

Here is the link to my Gradle: https://github.com/Nikhilgupta1891/RetryRecover/blob/main/build.gradle%20copy#L55

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly add

```
implementation 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.2-SNAPSHOT
```

and add

```
https://repo.spring.io/snapshot
```

to the repositories.

However, it's not been published with recent changes yet, you will need to build it locally and `mvn clean install` and add `mavenLocal()` to the repos.

Comment: I added as you suggested. But it is still NOT working. I have updated my gradle with your suggested changes - https://github.com/Nikhilgupta1891/RetryRecover/blob/main/build.gradle%20copy#L7. Can you please take a look and let me know..

Comment: Also, this is not a maven project. So commands like ```mvn clean install``` won't work. I tried going gradle refresh instead. But to no vain.

Comment: No. You need to clone the spring-retry project. It uses maven, not gradle. `mvn clean install` will install the snapshot into a local maven repo which gradle can then use. I am working on fixing the publish to the spring snapshot repo but it might take a day or so, because I am not familiar with its ci build service and need some help.

Comment: I can do those steps on the local machine, but my project will be deployed via Jenkins and in the pipeline, these manual steps won't work!

Comment: I understand that. That is why I am working on fixing the publish. Please bear with me. You should not commit changes that use snapshot versions anyway, unless you are only in development mode. In any case you will need to wait until the snapshot publishing is fixed, and a full release is available, before going into prod.

Comment: I have fixed the ci pipeline and the latest 1.3.2-SNAPSHOT is now in repo.spring.io/snapshot